# Accesses an object that "should" exist from another class

Tags: java

I am creating a program that simulates the distribution of a product.
The user enters a quantity and that quantity is then randomly divided among X number of distribution sites.

The structure of the program is a main that excepts the original quantity, then sends that quantity to the CPO (Central Processing Office) class. The CPO has a method where it instantiates the required number of distribution sites and another method that determines the value given to each site.

My problem is that I would like the main or a menu class to display the values of the distribution sites, but since they are instantiated within another class, the main does not see them.
Hence a command like System.out.println(D1);

Main File:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Welcome prompt, requests initial quanity of products to be ordered
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println(
            "\tWelcome to CPO Distribution "
                    + "\n\t  Order Placement Menu \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++){
        System.out.print("=");
    }
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the quantity of products to be distributed");
    System.out.print("Product Quantity: ");

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------        
    // Creates Order int to hold the value of the products entered
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    order = input.nextInt();
    while (order < 1){
        System.out.println("Please enter a value greater than 0");
        order = input.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++){
        System.out.print("=");
    }
    Cpo CPO = new Cpo(order);
    Cpo.dCreation();


    System.out.println(CPO);
    System.out.println(D1);
    System.out.println(D2);
}
```

CPO Class:

```
public class Cpo {
    private static int origin, quantity, site, distributionsites = 3;
    private static int D1Total, D2Total, D3Total;
    private static SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

    public Cpo(int origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
        quantity = origin;
        site = distributionsites;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get'r and Set'r for Order received from CPO
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    public int getOrigin() {
        return this.origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(int origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  instantiating Distributors
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void dCreation() {
        getDamount();
        Distributor D1 = new Distributor("D1",D1Total);
        getDamount();
        Distributor D2 = new Distributor("D2",D2Total);
        getDamount();
        Distributor D3 = new Distributor("D3",D3Total);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Method for distributing order to Distributors
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static int getDamount(){
        site = site - 1;
        int remainder = 0;
        if ( site == distributionsites ){
            remainder = rand.nextInt(quantity);
            quantity = quantity - remainder;

        } else if ( site == distributionsites - 1){
            remainder = rand.nextInt(quantity);
            quantity = quantity - remainder;

        } else if (site < 1){
            remainder = quantity;
            quantity = quantity - remainder;

        }
        return remainder;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n The CPO has dispersed an order of " + origin + " products among "
                + distributionsites + " Distribution Sites. \n There are " + quantity
                + " left." + "sites are " + site;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to persist the info so it become available after you use, you can do inmemory(ArrayList) or permanent(Database and file)

Comment: Think about class responsibility and where behavior/data belongs.  `Cpo` might need to be _aware_ of the `Distributor`s, but is it really `Cpo`'s responsibility to _create_ the `Distributor`s?

Comment: I was hoping that by instantiating the objects from the main file via a method from the CPO class.  I could then reference them by name. I am not allowed to use an array for this assignment. Am I then forced to perform those instantiations from the main? Part of my reason for wanting to avoid that was to keep the main short and the method for distributing the quantities in another class.